# Как передвинуть label в ячейке?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть ячейка `myCell`, у которой стиль `Subtitle`, она меня устраивает, но я в коде чуть расширил картинку слева от текста и теперь хочу передвинуть `label` заголовка и текст описания чуть чуть вправо, на картинке это *Yes, it is label* и *Detail*, как это можно сделать в коде?

Когда я это в редакторе пытаюсь передвинуть, оно двигает но сразу возвращает назад, подозреваю, что из-за того, что стиль ячейки предопределен.

[image: Скриншот из xcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `indentationLevel`. Что-то вроде такого:

```
[cell.contextView setIndentationLevel:SOME_NUMBER];
[cell.contextView setIndentationWidth:SOME_OTHER_NUMBER];
```